# JavaScript - control.style.display = "none"; and control.style.display = "";?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label, visibility

When I created a label I set it's display to none in the designer.

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" style="display:none;" Text="LABEL" asp:Label>
```

I use javascript to turn the label visible by:

```
var lbl = document.getElementById('label1');
lbl.style.display="";
```

WHen I do this the space is created where the label would be on the form but the label itself doesn't show up. I have tried

```
lbl.style.display="inline";
lbl.style.display="block";
```

just to see if the label would show up. Still nothing though. Just the extra space where the label would be is created.

Comment: Are you sure the element contains text? Is there any other style applied to the element?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `lbl.style.display="inline";`?

Comment: Felix King - only other style applied is color. And The element does for sure have text

Comment: I have done lbl.visibility = "hidden" but I don't much care for that because it still leaves the blank space. I like how lbl.display = "none" doesn't leave the blank space when the element is not being displayed.

Comment: check the lable using firebug or similar tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were saying

> WHen I do this the space is created where the label would be on the form but the label itself doesn't show up. I have tried

That makes me believe that somewhere in your CSS you may have `visibility` set to `hidden`. That normally covers the space of the element, but doesn't show it. The `display` controls whether or not the space is preserved for the element.

Comment: my css doesn't ever change visibility. I figued the same also.

Comment: @Johnny Whisman: well, you could try what happens if you set `visibility` to `visible`. Note that in your comment to your OP you said you set it to `hidden`, which in fact is the exact opposite.

Comment: With your answer I looked much deeper into my code and found that 1 little line was setting it's visibility to hidden. Thank you very much for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you have the control ID correct? Unless you set ClientIDMode to Static, the actual control ID will probably be something much longer than the ID you specify. Check the control's ClientID property.

Comment: Yes I was sure to set the CLientIDMode to static. I ran into that problem earlier today :)

Comment: I'm not sure then. I would expect `lbl.style.display="inline";` to work. Perhaps something else is going on. Maybe show your entire function and how it is called?